# How to host an open id authentication server?

Tags: hosting, openid

I want to host my own open id server (just as an experiment).  Does anyone know how to do this?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Check out the excellent article on the OpenID site, [Run your own identity server](http://wiki.openid.net/Run-your-own-identity-server), which gives you a ton of different options.

Comment: It seems that most of these projects are retired.